# Pynput keyboard listener

Tags: python, pynput

Hello i have problem becouse pynput keyboard listener don't work. I have some code and on the end I have this:

```
def on_press_key(key):
    print("Key pressed: {0}".format(key))


ac_thread = threading.Thread(target=ac_function, daemon=True)
ac_thread.start()
print('1')
keyboard_listener = KeyboardListener(on_press=on_press_key)
print("2")
mouse_listener = MouseListener(on_click=on_click_mouse)
print('3')
keyboard_listener.start()
mouse_listener.start()
keyboard_listener.join()
mouse_listener.join()
```

This prints are for test. Without lines that defines keyboard_listener everything works, but when I add keyboard listener it stucks at `print('1')`

Comment: Can we see the `ac_function`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it only needs to move `ac_thread.start()` under `print('3')`